# Counting up and down to specified number in order in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get this script to count up to a specified number and back down to a specified number as follows: 19200, 38400, 57600, 76800, 96000, 76800, 57600, 38400, 19200 — repeatedly. So far this is what I have but I cannot seem to make it count down in the order above, it restarts from 19200 again.

```
$(function() {
var seconds = 19200;
var timerId = setInterval(function() {
    seconds = seconds + 19200;
    $("#counter").text(seconds);

     if (seconds > "76800") {
        clearInterval(seconds);
         seconds = seconds - "19200";    
    }

}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little issue with the logic, the condition

```
if (seconds > "76800") {
```

would always try to keep the seconds above 76800.

Rather you would want a flag to track the direction of the count. Check out below:

UPDATED:

Working demo at

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBK2b/7/)

```
$(function () {
    var increment = 19200;
    var seconds = increment;
    var countUp = true;
    var timerId = setInterval(function () {
        $("#counter").text(seconds);

        if (countUp) {
            seconds += increment;
        } else {
            seconds -= increment;
        }

        if (countUp && seconds > increment*4) {
            countUp = false;
        } else if (!countUp && seconds <= increment) {
            countUp = true;
        }

    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Whoops my bad, thank you! But how do you keep the count from returning to 0 and sticking at 19200 as its lowest number?

Comment: Updated the JSFiddle and the code above to reduce the hardcoded values and set the lower bounder to 19200 rather than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below function

```
$(function() {
    var seconds = 19200;
    action = 'add';
    var timerId = setInterval(function() {

    $("#counter").text(seconds);

    if (seconds == 96000) {
        action = 'remove';
    } else if (seconds == 19200) {
        action = 'add'
    }

    if (action == 'add')
        seconds += 19200;
    else if (action == 'remove')
        seconds -= 19200;

    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a little more elegant

```
var increment = 19200,
    seconds   = increment;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  console.log(seconds);
  seconds += increment;
  if (seconds > 76800 || seconds < 19200) {
    increment *= -1;
  }
}, 500);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macek/xBPY7/)